# How to get a column which type is float using linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to EF and Linq to entities. I want to get a column which name is "Value" which type is a float. My code is shown below. So when I called the below method I get an error on the line double price..... Input string was not in a correct format. Is there a way to return the column "Value" as a double? or how can I convert it to a Double. Thanks in advance.

```
 public double calculate_price(int code, int quatity)
    {
        using( var context = new DryTypeEntities())
        {
            var result = context.Table_Products.Where(p => p.Code == 3).Select(p => p.Value) ;            
            string something = result.ToString();
            double price = Convert.ToDouble(something);
            double quant = Convert.ToDouble(quatity);
            double total = price * quant; 
            return total ;                             
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns a collection of `Value`'s:

```
 var result = context.Table_Products
                     .Where(p => p.Code == 3)
                     .Select(p => p.Value);
```

This, then, stores the string representation of your collection in `something` (not what you intended):

```
string something = result.ToString();
    // System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] or something equally unhelpful
```

That cannot be converted to a price, so this fails:

```
double price = Convert.ToDouble(something);   // uh, no.
```

Instead, one option is to get the first record:

```
 var result = context.Table_Products
                     .Where(p => p.Code == 3)
                     .Select(p => p.Value);
                     .First();
```

Or, if there's guaranteed to be exactly one match for "code" 3:

```
 var result = context.Table_Products
                     .Where(p => p.Code == 3)
                     .Select(p => p.Value);
                     .Single();
```

Now `result` contains one `Value` and you can work with that single value.

There's other stuff to consider too *(i.e. what if there's no matching records, what if there are multiple records to iterate through, etc.)*, but this should get you going again.

One last point - [consider using `decimal` for money values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) instead of `double`.

Comment: `and you can work with that single record` to ensure that is singe it is better to use `Single` :)

Comment: @Grant How do I check for no matching records. When inserting a new record. you use int num = context.SaveChanges. But how do you do it on my case ?

Answer (score 1):

The select will not return the value you expect.

Change to.

```
var result = context.Table_Products.Where(p => p.Code == 3).Select(p => p.Value).FirstOrDefault() ;
```

You probably should check that result isn't null.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that A) `something` is a string and not a double, and B) the contents of `something` are not in the correct format to be converted to a double.

You haven't shown what something `contains` but that's what you should be looking at.

So guessing at what you want, you might want to do something like this:

```
using( var context = new DryTypeEntities())
{
    var result = context.Table_Products.Where(p => p.Code == 3).Select(p => p.Value) ;            
    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(r);
        // There is no quatity returned by your query
    }
}
```

Note 1: Your query specifically selects `Value`, and so the result only contains the Value column. There is no `quatity` value returned by the query.

Note 2: Your query returns a collection (a group of zero or more elements), not just one element. I think this is what you really want:

```
using( var context = new DryTypeEntities())
{
    var result = context.Table_Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Code == 3);            
    return result.Value * result.quantity;
}
```